# DB2 Select with Condition

Tags: db2

How can I rewrite the Select statement to retrieve `TRUE or FALSE` in the tempBool variable?
For now I got only true if the `length is > 100` and otherwise an empty result.

```
SELECT TRUE into tempBool--or FALSE 
FROM ABC
HAVING COUNT(*) > 100;
```

Comment: Rewrite it to use CASE with > 100 returning TRUE, else FALSE

Comment: Just in case: + remove `HAVING`, of course, which should be clear...

Comment: `select count(*) > 100 from abc`. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9gk9iVz4).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT CASE
   WHEN COUNT(*) > 100 THEN true ELSE false END
INTO :tmpBool   
FROM ABC;
```